# Python pandas modin - no module found

Tags: python, pandas, module

I am using anaconda and just tried:

```
pip install modin
```

that finished without issue.
Then created very simple python script and in it only have one line:

```
import modin.pandas as pd
```

Error that I am getting:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'modin.pandas'; 'modin' is not a package
```

If I use regular `panda` package - all works fine.

In addition tried:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install pandas==0.23.4  --force-reinstall
pip install modin  --force-reinstall
pip install ray  --force-reinstall
```

But that did not help (same error).
What should be done?

Comment: The pip you used to install would've been for a different version of python (likely 2.x) than the one you invoked (likely 3.x).

Comment: How to make sure using correct `pip`? (for Anaconda Virtual Environment that am using)

Comment: How do you invoke the script? What is the command?

Comment: What are the outputs of `which pip` and `which python` (or `where pip` and `where python` on Windows)?

Comment: cmd locate the python version you are using then run pip . or just go to your environment set the path .

Comment: `which pip` gives `/Users/myusername/anaconda3/envs/py36/bin/pip`.

And `which python` gives `/Users/myusername/anaconda3/envs/py36/bin/python`

Comment: Check the modin dependencies https://modin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#dependencies and make sure you have the correct versions of each installed

Comment: Thanks, please see updated question. Tried exact version without success.

Answer (score 3):

You should use:

`pip install modin[ray]` as python suggests

Comment: you probably mean "as the modin documentation suggests": https://modin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

Answer (score 1):

Try work in an environment:

```
conda create --name modin python=3.6 pandas modin --channel conda-forge
```

So we created environment called modin with Python 3.6. pandas and mod in from conda-forge channel. Let conda deal with extra-requirements. Activate the environment and install other packages.

*Note* ray is yet to be support in Windows. Windows usera use WSL

```
conda activate modin
conda install ray -c bioconda
```

Test if everything is okay:

```
python -c "import modin.pandas as pd"
```

If no error! You are good to go!

Comment: ```conda create --name modin python=3.6 ray=0.6.3 pandas=0.23.4                                                                                                                                                                       

Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - ray=0.6.3```

Comment: Try now! Changed logic of installing

Comment: Now got no error but weird message: ```Waiting for redis server at 127.0.0.1:15633 to respond...```

Comment: that is strange. It appears that that is the issue with the package locations. Try again but first install ray, then modin. See if the problem is with ray or modin package.

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel, FYI I am getting `modin 0.4.0 has requirement numpy<=1.15.0, but you'll have numpy 1.16.2 which is incompatible.`
`modin 0.4.0 has requirement ray==0.6.2, but you'll have ray 0.6.5 which is incompatible.`

Comment: Where can I find their suggestions for the compatible python and pandas version for each installation of modin?

Comment: It has been a long time. Packaging is changing;) I have update this answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Anaconda environment then you should firstly install **modin** through following command:

```
conda install -c conda-forge modin
```

Then import

```
import modin.padas as pd
```

Answer (score 0):

This `pip install 'modin[dask]'`works for me.

I am using Python 3.9.

Answer (score 0):

what is your script name? I had same issue when I named my script as modin.py. After I renamed it to something else, the issue was gone.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33484846)